# Fetch two control values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have two controls whos code are run time rendered as below:

```
ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_3c1ba10a_23ec_4ab5_b303_18f8bd7ee7e7_ctl00_gdvItinerary_ctl03_txtTravelDate      
ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_3c1ba10a_23ec_4ab5_b303_18f8bd7ee7e7_ctl00_gdvItinerary_ctl04_txtTravelDate
```

How do I fetch the values of above two controls using jQuery?

Comment: Pardon me but whats this ? If its `id` of control, you can use `$('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_3c1ba10a_23ec_4ab5_b303_18f8bd7ee7e7_ctl00_gdvItinerary_ctl03_txtTravelDate')` for first one and same for the second one

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Please edit the quesiton to provide more information and show precisely what's happening, what you're trying and what the desirved effect is. You've posted two strings, and I have no idea what they are or what they refer to.

Comment: @arttronics `:)` thanks man! will add my comments again

Comment: @Jashwant `:)` since you are keen bruv, these are user control (.net) dynamically added values hence these `ctl` to start with, For the OP, I would recommend to add **CLass** attribute to the input or html element and access it like this `$('.class_name').val()`, hope this helps! :))

Comment: If the rendered `id` is not going to change everytime, this should work. Also, I remember `.net` 4.0 introduced a property which let you keep client id. Also, there's some `clientid` method too.

Comment: @Jashwant correct indeed, `:)` ! +1 for both set a thoughtful answer I will up vote you +!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the valuable comments, these was the answer i was looking for, could you please post these as answers so that i can accept one

Comment: @Jashwant you can reply! I am fine so won't reply this question, have a good one!

Comment: @PeteEngineer, See my reply, it will surely help you. Also, I am not very good at asp.net so please check if it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple - use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
var firstValue  = $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_3c1ba10a_23ec_4ab5_b303_18f8bd7ee7‌​e7_ctl00_gdvItinerary_ctl03_txtTravelDate').val();
var secondValue = $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_3c1ba10a_23ec_4ab5_b303_18f8bd7ee7e7_ctl00_gdvItinerary_ctl04_txtTravelDate').val();
```

You should seriously consider using shorted `id`s. From these `id`s alone, I have *absolutely no idea* what the value represents.

You can make it more readable with:

```
var baseID = "#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_3c1ba10a_23ec_4ab5_b303_18f8bd7ee7‌​e7_ctl00_gdvItinerary_";

var firstValue  = $(baseID + 'ctl03_txtTravelDate').val();
var secondValue = $(baseID + 'ctl04_txtTravelDate').val();
```

Comment: hard coding asp.net generated client ids are a very bad idea...if you changes the container tree of this control your code will be broken...try use <%= usercontrol.ClientID %> instead

Comment: @AHMED: not an asp.net user myself. Question wasn't tagged with it either. You're right though.

Answer (score 1):

In asp.net , your control's `id` is changed at runtime.

If you id was `mycontrol`, it would be changed to `blahblahblahmycontrol` (`id` will be there at the end)  at client side.

So,

if you have an asp.net control (textbox), like below,

`<asp:TextBox runat='server' id='mytxtbox'></asp:TextBox>`

you can do,

```
$("input[id$='mytxtbox']").val();
```

*It selects all `input` tags ending with `_mytxtbox`*

or you can do something like this if the javascript is on the same .aspx file

```
$('#<%=mytxtbox.ClientID %>').val()
```

**If you are using asp.net 4.0,**

You can add `ClientMode` property to `Static`

`<asp:TextBox ID="mytxtbox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>`

This will retain the id of `TextBox` to `mytxtbox`

So, you can do,

```
$('#mytxtbox').val();
```

Yes, you can also, see the source code and use the converted `id` like this,

```
var txtboxValue = $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_SPWebPartManager_g_3c1ba10a_23ec_4ab5_b303_18f8bd7ee7‌​e7_ctl00_gdvItinerary_ctl03_txtTravelDate').val();
```

But its not recommended.